# Display all of a single user's content on a profile page in django

Tags: python, django

I want to create a public-facing user profile page that displays these three things:

1-the user's Profile (model-singular-) data (image, name, email, etc..)

2-The Blog (model -list of posts-) posts the user has published.

3-The Art (model -list of art pieces-) pieces the user has published.

All three of these models have fields that tie them to their User.

So far I have been able to display all of these models on one page, but I cannot figure out how to sort them down to only display the content of the user who's profile page is being visited.

I am trying to display all of this data on a ListView view, not sure if that is the correct move. I have been searching around for hours trying to find how to adjust the `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` but I can't figure out how to grab the `<pk>` from the url (i.e. artist/44). I also tried putting `<username>` in the url but I wasn't able to grab that either.

The two views below are the views I have been working on. One uses (username) and the other uses (id) in the url:

**views.py**

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=username).order_by('date_posted')


class ArtistProfileListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile_list'
    template_name = 'blog/artist_detail.html'
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = get_object_or_404(User, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Profile.objects.filter(id=current_user).order_by('-user')
```

**urls.py** (im planning on only keeping one of these)

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('artists/<pk>/', ArtistProfileListView.as_view(), name='artist-detail')
```

**blog/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Art(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='default_thumbnail.jpg', upload_to='art_thumbnails')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('art-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**users/models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Artist', 'Artist'),
        ('Patron', 'Patron'),
        ('Broker', 'Broker')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    user_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    profile_bg_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default='default_bg.jpg', upload_to='profile_bg_pics')
    user_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Comment: Why is `ArtistProfileListView` a `ListView`? you have a `OneToOneField` between User and Profile meaning you expect it to display only one object...

Comment: I switched it to a ListView to use the `get_query` and `get_context_data` defs. I don't even know if that's a requirement but I was referencing an old project i'd done where I was able to get a lot of context data on a ListView. I am new to this so im not 100% sure on conventions. Do you think I can just pull this off with a def instead of class-based views?

Comment: There is another class based view for that `ListView` implies list (like the name). For a single object you should be using [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)